# matplotlib Change line color attributes based off other data

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, attributes, line

I am working on a few of my meteorology plots and I am trying to make them a little more visually friendly. The polar plot is called a hodograph and plots the windspeed vectors with increasing height. I want to make it so that the lowest 3 kilometers of data is say red, then 3-6km is say blue and such. Ive looked at possibly building my own coolor map but I am not sure how to go about implementing that. Any help would be much appreciated. Ive included a few screenshots and the basic hodograph code. The data used is simply an array with several columns: temperature, wind speed, wind direction, dewpoint, height in meters, ect.

```
#begin hodograph subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122,polar = True)
ax1.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2)
ax1.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax1.plot(wd,ws,'ro-')
```

[image: SKewt Log p with basic Hodograph]

Comment: Do you want it to go from blue to red, or would blue to red to green be just as good, which is a standard colormap (see brg in the bottom set of http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html ).  Either is possible, it's just a bit easier to use a built-in.

Comment: I would either manually create separate lines for each height 'bin' or return a line2d handle from `line = ax1.plot` and then iterate over the zip of the line.get_data() and your height list to `set_color` on each segment perhaps?

Comment: Thats actually what I ended up doing. I do a loop that separates the values between 0-3 3-6 6-9 and 9-12 km using some basic logic, then colors the line segments accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure out with help from a friend how to loop over that data and separate it with a loop. Once separated, each line segment gets plotted independently. [image: new hodograph]